Why am I getting "Error: grid.mongo.ObjectID is not a constructor"
I'm playing with gridfs-stream in nextjs (a react server component) and I'm getting Error: grid.mongo.ObjectID is not a constructor
here's my code:
import { writeFile } from "fs/promises";
import { join } from "path";
import Grid from "gridfs-stream";
import { connect } from "@/helpers/DBConfig.js";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const connection = await connect();

export default function ServerUploadPage() {
  async function upload(data) {
    "use server";

    const file = data.get("file"); // 'file' is the name attribute of the file input
    if (!file) {
      throw new Error("No file uploaded");
    }

    const bytes = await file.arrayBuffer();
    const buffer = Buffer.from(bytes);

    const gfs = Grid(connection.db, mongoose.mongo);
    const writeStream = gfs.createWriteStream({
      filename: file.name,
    });
    console.log("writeStream", writeStream);
    writeStream.write(buffer);
    writeStream.end();

    writeStream.on("close", () => {
      console.log("File uploaded successfully");
    });

    // With the file data in the buffer, you can do whatever you want with it.
    // For this, we'll just write it to the filesystem in a new location
    // const path = join("/", "tmp", file.name);
    // await writeFile(path, buffer);
    // console.log(`open ${path} to see the uploaded file`);

    return { success: true };
  }

  return (
    <main>
      <h1>React Server Component: Upload</h1>
      <form action={upload}>
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
      </form>
    </main>
  );
}

I tried removing the
conn.once('open', ...
because IO have read that it's deprecated
